# how to fix 'passing data from flask-socketio event handler to Flask-SQLAlchemy'

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

> I want to pass event json data from **flask-socketio** to flask-SQLalchemy

Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

    from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


    @socketio.on( 'my event' )

    def handle_my_custom_event( json ):

     #HOW TO PASS THE VALUE from this event to my database

     #AM i using import json or flask-json and how? any reference

      # usern = History(username=json.user_name)

      # messg = History(message=json.messg)

      # db.session.add(usern)

      # db.session.add(messg)

      # db.session.commit()

      print( 'recived my event: ' + str( json ) )

      socketio.emit( 'my response', json, callback=messageRecived )
```

This is not working. I am new to python-flask. please help any reference or explanation

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Please show how it doesn't work. Include the code, output, error messages and stack traces that you are getting.

Comment: @nitinr708: in several of your edits you are adding quote blocks to posts where that is inappropriate. Those edits should be rejected as "causes harm", but unfortunately the quality of the edits reviewing is not up to par here. Please only use quote formatting where someone/something is being quoted i.e. the voice does not belong to the writer.